# what would be regex expression for js

Tags: javascript, nsregularexpression

what would be the regular expression for

```
JIRA #R6K4118
```

I am using this, but it's not working:

patt=/JIRA #[a-zA-Z]{1,}\d+[a-zA-Z]{1,}[0-9]{1,}/gi;
patt.exec(patt);
comment=comment.replace(patt,"JIRA #$1$2$3$4");

It's returning `JIRA#R-6`

Where am I going wrong?

the desired output is

https://eteamproject.internal.ericsson.com/projects/R6K4118

Comment: We cannot help you if you do not provide a detailed explanation of your problem, i.e. what are you trying to capture or match? what is expected?

Comment: I edited a live demo into your question and cannot reproduce the problem. Possibly there is some context you omitted from  your initial question.

Comment: Maybe just try to use one capture group? `(JIRA #[a-zA-Z]{1,}\d+[a-zA-Z]{1,}[0-9]{1,})`

Comment: Please check the tags on your question. At least two of them don't make any sense given your question title mentions JavaScript.

Comment: am giving this input  patt=/JIRA #[a-zA-Z]{1,}\d+[a-zA-Z]{1,}[0-9]{1,}/gi;//R6K additional Link
        patt.exec(patt);
        comment=comment.replace(patt,"<a href= 'https://eteamproject.internal.ericsson.com/browse/$1$2$3-$4' target='_blank'>JIRA #$1$2$3$4</a>");

Comment: Do you need to check the format of the jira id? If not, just take all the characters after the # :) Lazy solution xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the string after `#` is structured just like the example then the regex is:

(Assuming you want to match the whole string)

`/JIRA #[a-z]\d[a-z]\d{4}/i`

The `/i` in the end makes it case insensitive, so the we don't need to match both upper and lowercase letters.

```js
const expression = /JIRA #[a-z]\d[a-z]\d{4}/i;
const result = "JIRA #R6K4118".match(expression);
console.log(result);
```

If you want to match just the string after `#` then use a positive lookbehind:

`/(?<=JIRA #)[a-z]\d[a-z]\d{4}/i`

```js
const expression = /(?<=JIRA #)[a-z]\d[a-z]\d{4}/i;
const result = "JIRA #R6K4118".match(expression);
console.log(result);
```